# How to stopPropagation and allow modal at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, bootstrap-modal

I have two buttons in a table row (`<tr>`). Whenever a button is clicked I have the following event handler to prevent the row to receive the click as well.

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

This prevent modally from opening as well.

I have the following buttons:

```
<tr> 
    <td>
        <a><button data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#emailModal" data-player="<%=JSON.stringify(player)%>" data-player_id="<%=doc.id%>" data-result="pass" data-recipient="<%=player.email%>" class="btn btn-outline-danger action-btn reject-btn">Reject</button></a>
        <a><button data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#emailModal" data-player="<%=JSON.stringify(player)%>" data-player_id="<%=doc.id%>" data-result="Approve" data-recipient="<%=player.email%>" class="btn btn-outline-success action-btn approve-btn">Approve</button></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I make sure that the event propagates to the modal so that it is launched/shown but does not propagate to the outer div (`<tr>`)?

**EDIT**:

```
<% players.forEach(doc => { %>
     <tr class="trow" onclick="document.location = '/leaderboard/<%=doc.id%>';">
```

Comment: `<button type="button"` and if you have a click handler on the tr, use stopPropagation

Comment: I was actually using `stopPropagation`. I mistakenly put `preventDefault` in the question because it was my attempt to debug it.

Comment: have you tried to open the modal through jquery in the button click after e.stopPropagation(). I.e $('#emailModal').modal('show');

Comment: Check the [target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) of the `click` event

Comment: why do you have a button wrapped in an `<a>`nchor tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `type="button"` and this

```
<% players.forEach(doc => { %>
 <tr class="trow" data-location="/leaderboard/<%=doc.id%>">
```

using

```
$("tr[data-location]").on("click",function(e)  { 
  if (!$(e.target).is(".btn")) {
    location = $(this).attr("data-location");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. A problem remains though, with your solution. I assign the route each row should point to based on the element on the loop when I am creating the rows. How can I know, based on your solution, where I should point the window to?

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Sometimes when clicking on the button in the row (such that the cursor moves from the row to the button in <1s), the row still receives the touch. 1 second is not a extraordinary time, quite normal actually. How to solve this problem?